# Date parsing and formating in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, datetime

I'm looking to do what may seem like an easy task but I find it to be an awful nightmare in Python 2.7.

I have a date string such as `Sat, 13 Dec 2014 13:52:00 -0500` to `Dec 13 2014, 13:52 am EST`

Any idea how I could achieve this, preferably without doing to much coding and logic implementation, but rather using a built in functionality or a popular 3rd party lib?

Note: my timezone is not EST.

The closest I've come to is:

```
import time
import email.utils

observationTime = email.utils.parsedate('Sat, 13 Dec 2014 13:52:00 -0500')
print time.strftime('%b %d %Y %H:%M %p %Z', observationTime)
```

But it produces:

```
Dec 13 2014 13:52 PM GMT Daylight Time
```

Comment: These are really two problems: (1) parsing a string to a datetime + timezone, and (2) formatting a datetime (+timezone) as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`dateutil`](http://niemeyer.net/python-dateutil) to parse the date string into a timezone-aware datetime:

```
import dateutil.parser as DP
observationTime = DP.parse('Sat, 13 Dec 2014 13:52:00 -0500')
# datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 13, 13, 52, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -18000))
```

Now, to print the timezone abbreviation EST requires that you convert the
timezone-aware datetime to the `'US/Eastern'` timezone. This can be done using [pytz](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz/).

This can not be done
automatically since there are other timezones, such as `'America/Bogota'`, which have the same utcoffset.

```
import pytz
eastern = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
observationTime = observationTime.astimezone(eastern)
print(observationTime.strftime('%b %d %Y %H:%M %p %Z'))
# Dec 13 2014 13:52 PM EST
print(observationTime.strftime('%b %d %Y %H:%M %z'))
# Dec 13 2014 13:52 -0500

bogota = pytz.timezone('America/Bogota')
observationTime = observationTime.astimezone(bogota)
print(observationTime.strftime('%b %d %Y %H:%M %p %Z'))
# Dec 13 2014 13:52 PM COT
print(observationTime.strftime('%b %d %Y %H:%M %z'))
# Dec 13 2014 13:52 -0500
```

(Note 13:52 is PM, not AM...)

Comment: hmm I don't like the idea that -0500 is not enough to work out the timezone automatically, but it is how it is... I think this will do the job for now at least, so I have to accept your answer. Many thanks for taking time to provide a solution.